# Implement a Binary Tree without using pre defined functions

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I want to implement a Binary Tree but I'm getting stuck over passing a method. This is my code:
There are two separate class: `xyz` and `BTree`. The methods of `BTree` are being used in `xyz`'s method `test`.

```
class xyz{    //main class
    public static void main (String args[]){
    xyz obj = new xyz();
    obj.test(n);    //takes input (int) from user
    }

    public void test(int n){
        BTree p = new BTree();
        int d1 = p.depth(    //I want ot pass a node here);
            //My question: How to pass an argument here as "Node" to be received properly by the method??
        ....
        ....
    }
}
class BT Tree{     //another different class
    private Node root;
    private Node node;
    private int size;
    public static class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        Node back;
        int data;
        int index;

    Node(int newindex) {
        left = null;
        right = null;
        back= null;
        data = 0;
        index = newindex;
    }
}
    public void BTree() {  //constructor
        root = null;
    }

    public int depth(Node node){     //Node pass will be correctly executed here
        if (node.index==root.index)
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1+depth(parent(node));
    }
}
```

My Question is: how to pass a Node through depth() method?

Comment: Why aren't `depth` and `parent` methods *inside* `Node`? Why should they be in `BTree`? (PS there's a difference between a binary tree and a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree))

Comment: I believe you need a public no-arg `depth()` method which will call private `depth(Node node)` method with root node as an argument. And as mentioned earlier, each node should track it's depth.

Answer (score 0):

> My Question is: how to pass a Node through depth() method?

It is unclear whether the design of your `BTree` class aims to hide the `Node` objects or not.

- If the `Node` objects are not intended to be hidden, then the answer is "you pass it just like any other object reference".  This begs the question of where do you get the Node reference from, and the answer to that is that your `BTree` class has to provide methods that allow external code (such as your `xyz` class) to get hold of node references.  It also means that your `depth` method needs to take account of the possibility that the `Node` is not a member of "this" `BTree`... at the moment.
- If the `Node` objects are intended to be hidden, then there is a problem in your `depth(Node)` method.

  - If external calling code cannot get hold of a `Node` what is the point of making this a public method.  Should it be a private method instead?
  - Should it be a public method, but with different semantics?  For instance, should it give the maximum depth of any node in the tree, rather than the depth of a given node?  (Note: that the implementation of `depth()` would need to be completely different ...)